# Is there any significant consequence if P does not equal NP-complete?

Tags: np-complete

I hear a lot on these forums about how if P=NP-complete how our lives would be better, is there any significant consequence if we found P to be not equal to NP-Complete?

Comment: Yes $-$ our lives wouldn't be better.

Comment: What are the consequences? One for sure is that RSA encryption would be in NP.

Comment: A constructive proof that P=NP means there is no digital security. Do I need to explain that that's not a good thing?

Comment: @djechlin A fun aside: **any** proof of P=NP would be constructive, in the following sense: there is a specific algorithm (perfectly concrete) that we can write down, that - if $P=NP$ - solves SAT in polytime. This is a fun silly exercise (it's not nearly as satisfying as we might hope . . . :P).

Comment: @NoahSchweber why's that? seems odd to me that we could prove any proof is constructive.

Comment: Noah Schweber, can you explain that further?  It sounds like you're talking about the same algorithm I linked in my other comment, but even if $P=NP$ that algorithm won't find the negative cases in polynomial time.  I don't see how a proof of $P=NP$ necessarily gives us a way to patch that up.

Comment: @DanBrumleve See the edit to my answer.

Comment: @djechlin See the edit to my answer.

Comment: Why do people feel they can downvote a valid question?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that $P\not=NP$ is roughly the "default" in terms of real-world applications. Currently we don't have an algorithm to solve NP-complete problems in polynomial time. Knowing "$P\not=NP$" would just reinforce that reality.

Now, this is a bit disingenuous - having a *proof* that $P\not=NP$ would almost certainly involve huge new ideas, which themselves would have important impacts - but the mere *fact* that "$P\not=NP$" wouldn't obviously lead to anything new in the "real world."

---

To avoid clogging the comment thread above, let me give an attempt at an explicit polytime SAT-solver (assuming P=NP) here. **As Dan Brumleve shows below, this doesn't quite work.**

Let $\{(T_i, p_i): i\in\mathbb{N}\}$ be a list of all pairs of the form (Turing machine, polynomial), ordered "reasonably" (there's some coding considerations here which I'm going to sweep under the rug). Now suppose I am given an instance $\sigma$ of SAT. I'll now run a potentially $(\vert\sigma\vert+2)$-stage procedure:

- **Stage 0.** Run $T_0(\sigma)$ for $p_0(\vert\sigma\vert)$-many steps. If it halts, check the answer (polytime!); if it's correct, halt and output it. If it's incorrect, or if it hasn't halted in time, move on to . . .
- **Stage 1.** Run $T_1(\sigma)$ for $p_1(\vert\sigma\vert)$-many steps. If it halts, check the answer (polytime!); if it's correct, halt and output it. If it's incorrect, or if it hasn't halted in time, move on to . . .

.
.
.

- **Stage $\vert\sigma\vert$.** Run $T_{\vert\sigma\vert}(\sigma)$ for $p_{\vert\sigma\vert}(\vert\sigma\vert)$-many steps. If it halts, check the answer (polytime!); if it's correct, halt and output it. If it's incorrect, or if it hasn't halted in that time, EXIT THIS LOOP . . .
- **Stage $\vert\sigma\vert+1$.** . . . And just solve $\sigma$ by brute force.

Now if $P=NP$, then there's some pair $(T_i, p_i)$ such that $T_i$ solves SAT in $p_i$ time. Then it's easy to check that for $\sigma$ an instance of SAT, $T(\sigma)$ solves $\sigma$ in time roughly $$\sum_{j\le i}p_j(\vert\sigma\vert).$$

(In particular, if $P=NP$ then the "brute force" option is taken on only finitely many instances.)

Comment: Furthermore, a proof that $P=NP$ wouldn't necessarily make our lives better either.  And I don't just mean that a SUBSET-SUM solver might involve huge constants or exponents, it might be entirely non-constructive.  Note that if $P=NP$ we already have an algorithm that in polynomial time can find a solution if one exists, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_versus_NP_problem#Polynomial-time_algorithms

Comment: @DanBrumleve Indeed, and see my comments to djechlin above.

Comment: Note how absolutely godawful the runtime of the algorithm above is. In particular, since we need these pairs ordered the same way as $\mathbb{N}$, there's no way to prevent $(T_i, p_i)$ being the "right" pair with $p_i$ linear (say), but $p_{i-1}$ being a trillionth-degree polynomial (which would lead to a trillionth-degree runtime, roughly). Not to mention all the constants built in  . . .

Comment: Presumably the TMs output a witness, because we can check the answer in polytime.  But what if we are given an unsolvable instance?  It seems like we also need a "constuctive" proof of $NP=co-NP$ to make this work.  I think this is essentially the same algorithm on wiki.  Am I missing something here?

Comment: Hm, this does seem to use $NP=coNP$. I remember this being fixable, though . . .

Comment: Note that wiki calls it a "semi-algorithm".

Comment: Another fun fact that I remember working out while studying this is that, if you set up the parameters correctly (spend $2^{-i}$ fraction of the time running TM #i in parallel checking answers as they halt, no need for for the $p_i$), then this is the _best_ semi-algorithm for SAT, up to some log factors maybe and of course a huge constant, but you can't beat that exponent.  And it's the best in the same sense even when $P \ne NP$!

Comment: (I should probably clarify that I don't really mean parallel, I mean increment a counter in a loop, let $i$ be the exponent of the largest power of $2$ dividing the counter, then run one step of $T_i$.)

Comment: ... and I realize now that for it to be the "best" we need a computational model where the above loop iterates in constant time or close to it, which a TM is not, but I think it works to create a SAT solver on a RAM for example that is as fast (up to log factors and constants) as the fastest TM SAT solver.  I'll have to stop soapboxing and mull this over some more.